# Custom TruncFunc in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a Django model with the following structure:

```py
class BBPerformance(models.Model):
    marketcap_change = models.FloatField(verbose_name="marketcap change", null=True, blank=True)
    bb_change = models.FloatField(verbose_name="bestbuy change", null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="created at", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="updated at", auto_now=True)
```

I would like to have an `Avg` aggregate function on objects for every 3 days.
for example I write a queryset that do this aggregation for each day or with something like `TruncDay` function.

```py
queryset = BBPerformance.objects.annotate(day=TruncDay('created_at')).values('day').annotate(marketcap_avg=Avg('marketcap_change'),bb_avg=Avg('bb_change')
```

How can I have a queryset of the aggregated value with 3-days interval and the index of the second day of that interval?

Comment: Hi, did you write a solution for this? It would be great if you could share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's impossible on DB level (and Trunc is DB level function) as only month, days weeks and so on are supported in [Postgres](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date_trunc/#:%7E:text=Introduction%20to%20the%20PostgreSQL%20date_trunc,with%20a%20level%20of%20precision.) and [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79).

So what I would suggest is to use `TruncDay` and then add python code to group those by 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work, although it's slightly ugly.

If you get the difference in days between each row's date and the min date you can then take the [Mod](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#mod) of this difference to work out how many days you need to shift to get "middle" date. This middle date can then be grouped on using a values query

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import F, IntegerField, Avg, Min, DurationField, DateField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Mod, Extract

BBPerformance.objects.order_by(
    'created_at'
).annotate(
    diff=F('created_at__date') - BBPerformance.objects.aggregate(min=Min('created_at__date'))['min']
).annotate(
    diff_days=Cast(Extract('diff', 'days'), output_field=IntegerField())
).annotate(
    to_shift=Mod('diff_days', 3) - 1
).annotate(
    grouped_date=Cast(F('created_at__date') - Cast(F('to_shift') * datetime.timedelta(days=1), output_field=DurationField()), output_field=DateField())
).order_by(
    'grouped_date'
).values(
    'grouped_date'
).annotate(
    marketcap_avg=Avg('marketcap_change'),
    bb_avg=Avg('bb_change')
)
```