# How to do custom truncation of date in Django ORM?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, orm

I have two `sql` queries which which does some specific truncation on dates. I have posted the queries below

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

time_diff_in_minutes = 60 * 24
start_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
end_time = start_time - timedelta(minutes=time_diff_in_minutes)


# 4 days interval (created_at, cost are columns in db)
sql = "select date_trunc('month', created_at) + (date_part('day', created_at)::int - 1) / 4 * interval 
'4 day' AS custom_gran, avg(cost) from some_table where created_at between '{}' and '{}' group by 
zoom_gran order by zoom_gran;".format(start_time, end_time)


# 4 hours interval (created_at, cost are columns in db)
sql = "select date_trunc('day', created_at) + date_part('hour', created_at)::int / 4 * 
interval '4 hour' AS custom_gran, avg(cost) from some_table where created_at between '{}' and '{}' 
group by zoom_gran order by zoom_gran;".format(start_time, end_time)
```

Now in `django` models I know basic truncation such as `hours`, `days`, `months` etc. So If I had to write a `daily` truncation or `hourly` truncation, this is how I would do it

```
# daily truncation
result = SomeTable.objects.filter(created_at__gte=start_time, created_at__lte=end_time)
.annotate(daily=Trunc("created_at", "day")).values_list("daily")
.annotate(avs=Avg("cost"))

# hourly truncation
result = SomeTable.objects.filter(created_at__gte=start_time, created_at__lte=end_time)
.annotate(hourly=Trunc("created_at", "hour")).values_list("hourly")
.annotate(avs=Avg("cost"))
```

I found a Stack overflow question regarding this ([Custom TruncFunc in Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70833411/custom-truncfunc-in-django-orm)) but I didn't quite understand the solution (even the answerer claims there is no direct way and the query gets ugly).

How do I achieve custom truncation in `django` ORM? Is there any simpler way?